# im having trouble with indexing these arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help with this. im trying to make it so that it checks the `test` array for duplicates and puts them to their corresponding places in the `track` array but it doesn't work for some reason? It only prints the unedited version of `track`, even though i called the `check()` function (which edits the `track` array) before logging it.

```
var test = ["a","a","e","r","t","e","t"];

var track = ["_","_","_","_","_","_","_",];

function check(letter) {
    this.letter = letter;
    var n = [];
    for(var x=0;x<test.length;x++){
        if(text[x] !== letter) {
            continue;
        } else {
            n.push(x);
        }
    }
    for(var c=0;c<n.length;c++) {
        track[n[c]] = letter;
    }
}

check("t");
console.log(test.join(" ")+"\n"+track.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at errors when running this code?

you have a syntax error on line where you check the letter in the first loop, should be test instead of text

```
if(test[x] !== letter) {
```